# Jupyter Dynamic Classes causes AttributeError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use JDC on my notebook for the following class

cell 1

```
import jdc
....
```

cell 2

```
class pre_proc (object):
    def __init__ (self, data = None, wordlist = None):
        ...
        self.__lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
        ...
```

cell 3

```
%%add_to pre_proc
   def lemmatize(self, token):
   ...
            word_Final = self.__lemmatizer.lemmatize('not', self.__tag_map[tag[0]])
   ...
        elif word.isalpha():
            word_Final = self.__lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, self.__tag_map[tag[0]])
   ...
    return clean_tok, lem_word
```

It works fine when I put everything in one class, but when I applied JDC, the following error occurs.

```
AttributeError: 'pre_proc' object has no attribute '__lemmatizer'
```

This apparently happens due to the `__` at the beginnning of the attribute name. Despite the redundancy of python private parameter, then how do we apply private parameter while using JDC?

Comment: i guess double underscore is the issue.

Comment: Thank you, apparently it is the double underscore. I will edit the question.